# How to organize custom Frameworks in Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, shared-libraries, project-organization

Imagine I create three separate Xcode projects, each its own Github repository:

- One for my iPhone app (App) and
- Two for each of my custom frameworks (Foo & Bar)

Dependencies

- App depends on Foo & Bar
- Foo depends on Bar

Actions

- Add the Foo & Bar repos as submodules of the App repo in a folder named `Libraries`
- Add the Foo & Bar projects as subprojects of the App project
- Link the Foo & Bar frameworks to the App target

From the App project, I can now run & test App and test every framework.

But, if I open the Foo project independently, I cannot build it.

Is there a clean way to make each project run/test on its own?

I know about workspaces, but I don't see how that'd solve my problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply add the Bar project as a subproject of Foo.

This creates a project reference but doesn't copy any code.

Now, you can open and build & test the Foo project independently.